# TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff' when using CustomUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-custom-user

I am Creating a Custom User using AbstractBaseUser, but anytime I try to create a superuser, it says

```
TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'
user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\user1\django\customuserproject\users\models.py", line 24, in _create_user
```

How do I solve this problem? I have checked other StackOverflow posts on this issue, but they didn't help me. I haven't tried with a regular user yet (I need a superuser to create a regular user), but I am sure it would be the same thing

My *models.py*:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,            
            is_staff=is_staff, 
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser, 
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now, 
            **extra_fields
        )
        #user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user=self._create_user(email, password, True, False, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)        
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)  
    display_name = models.CharField(('display name'), max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.
    
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name'] # Email & Password are required by default.
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('user')
        verbose_name_plural = ('users')
        #db_table = 'auth_user'
        abstract = False
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        if self.first_name:
            return self.first_name
        elif self.display_name:
            return self.display_name
        return 'You'
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.email
    
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.email,)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):        
        return self.is_superuser

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active
```

Comment: You've redefined `is_staff` to be a property on your model, you should probably remove the property

Comment: You defined a field `is_staff`, but later a property `is_staff` that *overrides* the `is_staff` field, and thus the field no longer exists. It is not necessary *at all* to define such properties.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem and @Iain Shelvington. So should i also remove the properties for *is_active*, and *is_superuser*?

Comment: @David.B probably best to remove them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Iain Shelvington, @Willem Van Onsem, and @7u5h4r.

I solved the problem by removing all the properties I declared, while leaving only the variables: *is_staff*, *is_superuser*, *is_active*.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `getter` and `setters` with `@property` they work a lot better and are clearly implemented.

```py
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0

    # using property decorator
    # a getter function
    @property
    def age(self):
        print("getter method called")
        return self._age

    # a setter function
    @age.setter
    def age(self, a):
        if(a < 18):
            raise ValueError("Sorry you age is below eligibility criteria")
        print("setter method called")
        self._age = a
```